# What is best way to use JQuery in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery

What is the best way to use jquery in asp.net, should I use controls or write inline or mix of both.
Controls are easier to use and save time and Writing jquery in page give more control but take more time. Not all (I mean commonly used) plugins are supported by controls.

There are many jquery controls available on codeplex. If you use any, then tell me which one and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JQuery in your ASP.NET application in the same way as using jQuery in any application. Using jQuery with UserControls is a great way to encapsulate functionality and is definitely advised.

The ones to use very much depend on your requirements, You can have a look at the rating from people at www.jquery.com for some idea on how good they are but would advise testing them yourself to see if they do what you require on the platforms you are building for.